# convert string to datetime in ado.net

Tags: string

I am trying to save data into my database using a vb form. I am using a datetimepicker to insert the date into my database. Here's an example

```
saveCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("A_BOOKDATE", abookdatePicker1.Text).DbType = DbType.DateTime
```

In my database i set its attribute to time ,now the thing is i used the same line of code on another database and it worked but this one is giving this error
'Failed to convert parameter value from string to datetime'

How do i convert this string to datetime.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTimePicker.Value` instead of `DateTimePicker.Text`:

```
saveCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("A_BOOKDATE", abookdatePicker1.Value) _
                      .DbType = DbType.DateTime
```

(If you ever actually *have* to convert a string to a `DateTime`, use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, but in this case it's better not to use the string representation at all.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use

[Convert.ToDateTime Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) (this one will return a datatime object or throw and exception)

[DateTime.TryParse Method (String, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) (this one returns the datetime as an output parameter, returns null on failure)